# Is it possible to know the change in size of a database table per day over the past few days?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to know how much did a specific table grow in size per day over the last week?, is there any query or statistical tool in SQL developer to do that.
The RDBMS is an Oracle 11g Rac

Comment: At first, you need to have a column `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses MMON background process to collect AWR statistics. Assuming it's not disabled (show parameter statistics_level should return TYPICAL or ALL since BASIC does not collect advisories or statistics), you can use the views dba_hist_seg_stat and dba_hist_snapshot like below. Replace the table name (your_table_name) and the dates (21-JAN-2019 / 28-JAN-2019) accordingly:

```
select   obj.owner, obj.object_name, 
         to_char(sn.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'RRRR-MON-DD') start_day,
         sum(a.SPACE_USED_DELTA) block_increase_bytes
from     dba_hist_seg_stat a,
         dba_hist_snapshot sn,
         dba_objects obj
where    sn.snap_id = a.snap_id
and      obj.object_id = a.obj#
and      object_name = 'your_table_name'
and      end_interval_time between to_timestamp('21-JAN-2019','DD-MON-RRRR') 
         and to_timestamp('28-JAN-2019','DD-MON-RRRR')
group by obj.owner, obj.object_name, 
         to_char(sn.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'RRRR-MON-DD')
order by obj.owner, obj.object_name, start_day
/
```

Note: A negative in block_increase_bytes indicates that row data in the table has been deleted or purged.

Comment: Thanks for your reply